# Is there any way to export a Go callback with const parameters?

Tags: go, cgo

Having this in Go:

```
//export foo
func foo(bar *C.char) { ... }
```

I can't call it in C++ this way:

```
foo("Hello");
```

Currently I'm resorting to a wrapper in C++:

```
inline void go_foo(const char *bar) {
    foo(const_cast<char *>(bar));
}
```

and then calling `go_foo("Hello")`.

Is there an alternative approach to obtain Go callbacks that carry parameter constness?